# vim shortcut to open a file with current directory populated

Tags: vim

I'm trying to add a key mapping so that it opens up command and populate it with :e /path/to/current/file

I can get the current directory using :pwd but I'm having a trouble to use it in the mapping

I think it will be along the lines of setting pwd to a variable and use that variable as such:

```
noremap <C-q> <C-o>:e *pwdvariable*<Space>
```

Should I create a function to perform this?

Comment: It isn't exactly what you're doing, but if you haven't looked at NERDTree it might be interesting.  I've used it to browse files in the same directory.

Comment: Adrian, maybe it would be better to explain what is it that you're trying to do in the first place?

Comment: @Idigas: In short, I want to map <C-q> to :edit /path/to/current/folder but without executing it.

Comment: @AdrianGunawan - Aah, I see! Well, you probably want abbreviations then ... something along the lines of ":cabbrev <silent> ec e <C-R>=getcwd()<cr>". Am I somewhere close with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need

```
nnoremap <C-q> <C-\><C-n>:e <C-r>=fnameescape(expand('%:p:h'))<CR>
```

Comment: that is exacly what i'm looking for. I just added <CR> at the end so it automatically expands when I use that key

Comment: There should have already been `<CR>`: for unknown reason I forgot to write it.

Answer (score 1):

`%:p:h` will get the full path of the current file (without trailing slash). Read more in `:help filename-modifiers`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, what you have asked for, but maybe more helpful:  [Vim tip 64: Set working directory to the current file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip64): In short, add the following line to .vimrc:

```
 autocmd BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
```

Interesting for you would be also [Easy edit of files in the same directory](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easy_edit_of_files_in_the_same_directory).